# Javascript template string

Tags: javascript, string, ecmascript-6, template-strings

I need to create some substrings using the template string.
I try to use this code but I have some problem about the auto filling of the template.

```
        Object.keys(optionsParams).forEach(function (key) {
            let template = '&${key}=${value}';
            let value = optionsParams[key];
            url += template;
        });
```

`key` and `value` variables are not found.
What's the problem?

Comment: You aren't using a template literal, and you tried to use `value` before you defined it. Also consider using `Object.entries` instead, to get both the key and value at once

Comment: check out `var search = Object.entries(optionsParams).map(([key,value]) => \`${encodeUriComponent(key)}=${encodeUriComponent(value)}\`).join("&")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use template strings you need to use backticks ` instead of single or double quotes. Try the following code instead

```
Object.keys(optionsParams).forEach(function (key) {
    let value = optionsParams[key];
    let template = `&${key}=${value}`
    url += template;
});
```